# very low sound in Lenovo ideapad 110

Tags: drivers, sound

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in Lenovo ideapad 110 and the system is up to date and the sound is very low .. i tried alsamixer but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try allowing volume over 100% in system settings?

Comment: Yes and it is still very low